# "Technology" vs. "a technology"

Tags: nouns, indefinite-articles, expression-choice

> (Company) develops *transactional data technology* that aggregates information for payment service providers and merchants.

or

> (Company) develops ***a*** transactional data technology that aggregates information for payment service providers and merchants.

Which is correct?

Comment: Either one is fine; it depends on what you are trying to say. A third option would be _Tranzlogic develops a transactional data technologies that aggregate information for payment service providers and merchants._ You also might be interested in checking out [ell.se].

Comment: @JR Either one is not fine. They do not mean the same.

Comment: @Kris - I didn't say they meant the same thing. I said it depends on what one is trying to say (something you elaborate on in your answer). I only meant that both were grammatical (something you elaborate on in your answer). My comment was brief – but then again, there's no question here. I don't even know what the O.P. is asking – is this a *which is grammatical* question? A *should there be an article* question? A *what's the difference in meaning* question? It's hard to say for sure; this is just two sentences conjoined with an "OR".

Comment: Thank you for your prior comments. And to make my question clear, i want to know whether the article "a" is absolutely necessary to give the full meaning of the sentence. Or are both the sentences conveying the same meaning?

Comment: In that case, I'd point you to the answer provided, where Kris explains how the meaning changes based on whether or not the article is included. I'd also encourage you to be much more explicit about what you're asking if you ask questions in the future, whether you are asking here, on ELL. Generally speaking, it's hard to be too thorough.

Comment: They mean different things.  If the company "develops technology" it simply does development in its technical specialty.  If it is "developing a technology" (or "has developed a technology") then it means it's got some specific technique/process/architecture it's working on or has worked on.  One wouldn't say the company "develops a technology" at all (except perhaps in a speculative statement).

Comment: "Technology", like so many words in English, can be a "mass" noun or refer to something specific.  When it's uses as a "mass" noun (referring to a field of technology vs some specific formula or technique), you do not apply an article.  When it's referring to a specific formula or technique then the article is appropriate.

Comment: @J.R. ... _develops a transactional data technologies_???

Comment: @Edwin - Hmm... That was awhile ago; I don't know what I was trying to say there. That may have been a "pre-coffee comment."

Comment: @J.R. I don't usually approve of any of the DIY words and wannabee longer expressions that appear on ELU, but _pre-coffee comment_ might well make it into OED within a couple of years. I'll drop the scare quotes when I first use it in anger.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no other known/ implemented method of processing transactional data and the company deems it has built the "technology" to achieve that, then the expression does not require an indefinite article:

> … develops transactional data technology …

On the other hand, if there are several (competing) approaches to the problem of processing transactional data and the company has implemented its own (i.e., non-unique) method, then you need the indefinite article:

> … develops a transactional data technology …

HTH.

Comment: Did you mean "its own (i.e., unique) method"?

Comment: @MrHen No, I meant *its own (i.e., one of the non-unique)* methods. -- *non-unique* was a crucial factor, in the sentence.

Comment: Then I don't understand how your answer could be correct. Wouldn't the company need a unique method in order to get the article? "We develop a transactional data technology; it is unique."

Comment: @MrHen That should be easy. You may have to recheck how you look at 'unique,' that's where the difference in perspective lies I believe.

Comment: I think I see what you meant now. The use of "non-unique" after "own" confused me. It is kind of interesting that you could write "develops a non-unique technology" and "develops a unique technology" and mean roughly the same thing.

Comment: It "has developed a technology" or it "will develop a technology" or it "is developing a technology", but never "it develops a technology", except in a speculative context ("...if the company develops a technology...").  (And it has nothing to do with whether the technology in question is "unique".)  (Though it does have to do, to a degree, with whether the technology is specific or general.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a BSC (Hons) in information systems and I can understand how hard it is to phrase or define certain systems, as technology is evolving at such a rapid pace.  Aggregates in the context of this sentence suggests the plural and that there are many information systems involved.  If there is more than one the plural form of technologies should be used.

Please allow me to say that the correct term for these systems would appear to be Transactional Processing Systems.

To rephrase your sentence:

(Company) develops transactional processing systems that aggregate payment information for service providers and merchants.

Computer Applications or Specialised software may also be used instead of technology / transactional processing systems if the intended audience is not from a technical background.

In your sentence, the correct option would be the second sentence as technology is singular.  [See here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/TechnologyPluralSingular/bgnjmh/post.htm)

To use the sentence without an 'a' in it just change technology to technologies so that it reads:

(Company) develops transactional data technologies that aggregate information for payment service providers and merchants.

Does this help?